# SAML Vulnerability Note VU#475445 - Is Spring Secucity SAML2 affected?

Tags: spring-security, xml-parsing, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/475445 has just been disclosed.

Is this impacting `Spring Security` `SAML2`?

I can't see the `XML` parser used on `Spring Security SAML2` on the list of affected APIs.

Let us know.

Comment: I asked a similar question as a GitHub issue. [Link for reference.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5058) No response yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am the Spring Security project lead and I have verified that the exploit does not work against Spring Security SAML with the default settings. This was verified by a colleague as well.

If you change the default settings (set ignoreComments = false), your application becomes vulnerable.

Update: See https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/01/spring-security-saml-and-this-week-s-saml-vulnerability

Comment: See also this GitHub issue in the spring-security-saml project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/228